# how to improve quality with ffmpeg flv

Tags: ffmpeg

i'm haveing problem when converting movies to FLV, i get a lot of small squares in the picture.
maybe someone know why?
and how i can remove those squares and make picture better?
my code is:

> ffmpeg -i movie.mp4 -f mpegts -acodec libmp3lame -ar 48000 -ab 128k -s 320.240 -vcodec libx264 -b 320k -flags +loop -cmp +chroma -partitions +parti4x4+partp8x8+partb8x8 -subq 7 -trellis 1 -refs 1 -coder 0 -me_range 16 -keyint_min 25 -sc_threshold 40 -i_qfactor 0.71 -bt 200k -maxrate 10M -bufsize 10M -rc_eq 'blurCplx^(1-qComp)' -qcomp 0.6 -qmin 10 -qmax 51 -qdiff 4 -level 30 -g 30 -async 2 out.flv

thanks!

Answer (score 2):

i'm not noticing a -vpre setting,  in which you set the encoding speed, and a dozen various other quality options.  Slower speeds = better quality but longer encode time.

Comment: @Nik...: That's not a helpful edit.

Comment: Sample reference: http://rodrigopolo.com/ffmpeg/cheats.html

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry. my bad
my code is:

> ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -r 20 -ar 44100 -ab 60 -b 1600k -maxrate 10M -bufsize 10M -qcomp 0.6 -qmin 10 -qmax 51 -qdiff 4 -level 30 -f flv out.flv